# Modelform - validation on form field

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Excuse my newbieness with django, but I am trying to properly validate a formfield named: `domainNm`

**form**

```
class SubmitDomain(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Tld #Create form based off Model for Tld
        fields = ['domainNm',]

def clean_domainName(self):
    cleanedDomainName = self.cleaned_data.get('domainNm')
    if Tld.objects.filter(domainNm=cleanedDomainName).count > 1:
        errorMsg = u"Sorry that domain is not available."
        raise ValidationError(errorMsg)
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data

## This creates the form.
form = SubmitDomain()
```

Currently, if I enter in:

```
abcdefghidfghiqwertyuiopasdfghjklcvbndmsja.com
```

or

```
df.com
```

or

`df.com` (again)

Both are valid, but they shouldn't be.

It isn't checking if the domain already exists or not (as outlined in the `form`) - in which it should

I am not getting any errors either.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems here.

One, your `clean` method doesn't match the field name.  Instead of `clean_domainName` it needs to be named `clean_domainNm`.  At least as long as that's your model field name.

Two, your comparison `if Tld.objects.filter(domainNm=cleanedDomainName).count > 1:` is wrong.  `count` is a method - you need to call it.

```
if Tld.objects.filter(domainNm=cleanedDomainName).count() > 1:
```

Three, I think your logic is wrong.  That will allow the creation of a second instance of a given name, because `count()` will return 1, meaning the form is valid.  I think you want to check the `count()` against 0, or better yet use `exists()` instead:

```
if Tld.objects.filter(domainNm=cleanedDomainName).exists():
```

Better still, define the field to be `unique=True`.

Comment: It's a model-level attribute of the field.  In addition to form validation, it will be enforced at the DB level.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique

Comment: Great point with the model-level validation. I think this was required for it to show a tld exists error. Also great point with exists() . Thank you!

Comment: @Alasdair is correct to point out that you need to return the cleaned value, not the `cleaned_data` dictionary.